# Using Illuminate DB outside of Laravel, can't use DB::table()

Tags: php, eloquent

I have installed some `Illuminate` packages to use outside of Laravel. However I can't use any of the DB methods.

For example:

```php
$this->query = DB::table((new Vehicle())->getTable())->query();
```

The above gives me this error:

> Error: RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in /var/www/vendor/illuminate/support/Facades/Facade.php:218 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/app/Services/PickCarouselService.php(37): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic() #1

Within my Ide I get the following message on `::table`:

> Method 'table' not found in \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB

I can use models and everything just fine, just not DB directly, how can I fix this?

## Edit 1

How would I create my own instance of the DB facade? We do have the following, would it be something similar? If so, what would I pass into the `DatabaseManager` for the `Factory`?

```php
$app->instance(Database::class, (new Database($app))->boot()->getConnection());
$app->alias(Database::class, 'database');
```

## Edit 2

Don't think i'm doing this correctly as not too sure what I would pass in for the `app`.

```php
$app = new Application();

$app->instance(Database::class, new DatabaseManager(null, new ConnectionFactory($app)));
$app->alias(DatabaseManager::class, 'db');
```

```php
// Application

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Container\Container;

class Application extends Container
{
    protected $basePath = '/var/www';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bindPathsInContainer();
        $this->registerBaseBindings();
    }
...
```

Comment: did you install the database correctly from `composer require illuminate/database`?

Comment: I don't think you can use facades without having an application container available. The DB facade creates an instance of [`DatabaseManager`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php) so you could probably make one manually instead

Comment: check it's configuration [here](https://github.com/illuminate/database) too

Comment: @apokryfos How would I make one manually? See updated question.

Comment: @Joseph Installed correctly and config is correct.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden Yeah, as stated normal models work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Managed to figure out how to create a custom facade. But nice if I could use it like `DB::table`, but this works:

```
$app = new Application();

$app->singleton('db.factory', function ($app) {
    return new ConnectionFactory($app);
});

$app->singleton('db', function ($app) {
    return new DatabaseManager($app, $app['db.factory']);
});
```

```
$this->query = app()->db->table('tablename');
```

Comment: What might work getting facades to work is calling `\Illuminate\Support\Facade::setFacadeApplication($app)` using the `$app` object above